# How do you annoy the candy merchant?

Tags: candy-box

On the candy box [statistics page](http://candies.aniwey.net/stats.php) there is a figure for

> Number of saves which annoyed the candy merchant

How do you annoy the candy merchant and can you tell if you have already annoyed the candy merchant? Is it something you have to do explicitly, or is it something you do randomly or accidentally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you click on the ascii graphics of the candy merchant's items several times he will become annoyed. This will reduce the cost of certain items.

Comment: I thought dropping candy on the ground annoyed him.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [Pubby's suggestion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116849/8557) of clicking on the candy merchants wares, I've just worked out that you can also annoy him by clicking on his hat.